# How can I stop Calendar auto-complete from suggesting my ex?

Tags: calendar

After a divorce, I'd so much like MacOS (10.13)'s Calendar (10, 2195.4.3) to stop suggesting "Dinner with ----" every time I start typing "Dinner" and reminding me each time I want to do something that I did it with someone else for decades.

I haven't found a way to tell Calendar to stop, and I also haven't figured out how to remove all previous invites with their name. All approaches welcome short of dating someone with the same name.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Could I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/328322/edit) your question to clarify whether you're referring to the Calendar app within macOS or iOS? Also, what version of macOS (or iOS) are you running? Just use the app dit button to add any details anywhere you feel is right in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new calendar, delete the old one?